# Comprobar si fecha en formato timestamp tiene + de 12 horas

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Tengo un fecha en `timestamp` y quiero comprobar si esta tiene más de 12 horas con respecto a la hora actual. Estoy tratando de este forma

```
let timestamp = 1585872962;

if(timestamp > timestamp + (1 * 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    // CODE
```

Pero esto no me funciona el segundo parametro `timestamp + (1 * 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`, me genera una fecha de un año en el futuro.

¿Como puedo comprobar si mi fecha ya tiene 12hrs de haber sido creada con respecto a la hora actual?

Comment: javascript da el timestamp en milisegundos, a un timestamp como el que tenes ahí le faltarían dígitos ( o sacar el *1000 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes restar los timestamps y comprobar que la resta sea mayor a 12h.

```js
const hanPasado12Horas = (timestamp) => (new Date().getTime() - timestamp > 1 * 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

 // pruebas hechas con mi zona horaria
let today = (new Date()).setHours(13) // me da el timestamp de hoy a la 13 del mediodia

console.log(hanPasado12Horas(today)) // debería evaluarse a false

today = (new Date()).setHours(5) // me da el timestamp de hoy a las 5 madrugada

console.log(hanPasado12Horas(today)) // debería evaluarse a true
```